# How to remove part of a border with another element?

Tags: html, css

Hello im trying to make a navigation menu and when you are on a active link, I would like the bottom border to be on top of the border set by the header.
Does anyone know how to do this? Here is an example. https://i.stack.imgur.com/W16V9.png

```
header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    background-color: red;
    border-bottom: 2px solid white;
}

#nav {
    padding: 5px;
    border: 0.3em solid red;
    border-bottom: 0
}

#nav a {
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    padding: 0.5em;
}

#nav a.active {
    background-color: #203748;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 2px solid #ddd;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #686868;
}
```

jsfiddle here. http://jsfiddle.net/pc2W5/

Comment: How about some negative margin on ```#nav a.active```? something like this ```#nav a.active { margin-bottom:-2px; /*other styles*/ }```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking a cue from Bootstrap's tabs, use negative bottom margin to lay the active tab over the header border:

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/pc2W5/1

```
#nav a.active {
    margin-bottom: -2px;
}
```

To keep the text properly aligned among all tabs, also adjust padding:

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/pc2W5/2

```
#nav a.active {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```